# NodeJS and Python combined architecture?

Tags: python, node.js

Could you give me an idea/concepts (not in code) on how could I link NodeJS and Python?

Let's say,

- I have NodeJS up and running in PM2 (assuming I already know REST API) and I have a ton of **data sets** that I need to be ready to display to client side using socket.io (assumming I already know socket.io) as soon as possible.

I'm thinking to use Python. This is for me to implement the basics of machine learning.

In what concept should I start? I'd really love to hear your ideas.

Comment: Please let me know down below why this question should be downvoted. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Probably because the lack of [mcve]

Comment: Also because of http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ or because question is too broad.
But I agree, it is always nice to have a comment about a downvote.

Comment: ["How would I get started" questions are too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836).

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask for such broad things like system architectures, maybe it you are having an isolated problem with it and explain it well. There are BTW sibling sites of SO with different topics.

Comment: @Pitto: It's alright. Maybe I should conceptualize the problem statement before thinking for possible solution.

Comment: It is not easy to ask questions or provide answers to SO. 
But I love how it is always a lesson to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you seem to be assuming way too many things, okay from your description I would suggest you to have a look at concept called [microservice architecture](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html).

This is how it will work let us assume you want to build an online shopping application where you have 2 main scenarios first is sell all items on your website and second you want to recommend products to your user(Your ML comes into play over here)

So as you said you already know REST API so what you would do is create a microservice (Consider it as a small nodejs application(Using either express or sails or any other framework) which has APIs exposed for all shopping related business logic) also you end up using fromtend technology viz. angularjs for your client side code. You'll show all this shopping stuff by calling your nodejs REST APIs from your angularjs client code. Node provides socket support via [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Similarly you write a small microservice in python(using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Python-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio)) which takes your huge amount of data from datastore does all ML magic and returns recommended products for the particular user(which you received from your angularjs client application), and return it using Python-SocketIO to angularjs(or node application if you're maintaining your frontend logic there instead of angular).

You have provided very less detail so this is abstract view of what you can look into.

Comment: Thanks for very informative answer. Now, I'm getting it. It cleared up my mind in having a thought about combining the architecture of nodejs and python. (I've just started to code few months ago) I've heard microservices before in an event but I haven't figured it out yet. But don't worry I'll get my hands dirty for me to learn it.

I'll look into your suggestion and apologies for a very broad question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're Python oriented for your ML code I'd suggest you to reduce the list of skills you need to learn and/or improve using Python for everything.

You could use [Python-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), for example.